# How to aggregate pgr_dijkstra results by attribute?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I working with a table with a lot of points per road/street. I'm using pgRouting's `pgr_dijkstra` method to give me a path, but it returns too many points per road/street, I'd like to know if there is a built-in method in pgRouting to aggregate the results by column, in this case the same street name IF it exists. I want to transform the results table:

```
seq | cost |   street   |     st_asgeojson     |
----+------+------------+----------------------|
 1  |  2.5 |  Street 1  | {coordinates: {...}  |
 2  |  4.5 |  Street 1  | {coordinates: {...}  |
 3  |  2.1 |  Street 2  | {coordinates: {...}  |
 4  |  1.9 |  Street 2  | {coordinates: {...}  |
 5  |  2.9 |  Street 1  | {coordinates: {...}  |
 6  |  3.0 |            | {coordinates: {...}  |
 7  |  4.5 |            | {coordinates: {...}  |
```

into this:

```
seq | cost |   street   |     st_asgeojson     |
----+------+------------+----------------------|
 1  |  7.0 |  Street 1  | {coordinates: {...}  |
 2  |  4.0 |  Street 2  | {coordinates: {...}  |
 3  |  2.9 |  Street 1  | {coordinates: {...}  | 
 4  |  3.0 |            | {coordinates: {...}  |
 5  |  4.5 |            | {coordinates: {...}  |
```

the current query is something like this:

```
SELECT seq, cost::double precision, street::character varying(192), 
    ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) 
    FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id,    
                              source::integer,
                              target::integer,
                              cost::double precision AS cost 
                              FROM my_table,                                                                                      
                                  get_nearest_vertex_to_lon_lat(lat_st, long_st),       
                                  get_nearest_vertex_to_lon_lat(-9.1511504, 38.7487786), 
                                        false, 
                                        false) 
    a LEFT JOIN my_table b ON (a.id2 = b.gid);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not pretty, but I think this should work for you:

```
WITH p AS (SELECT seq, cost::double precision, 
     street::character varying(192), geom,
   -- if a street name is not same as previous street name,
   -- its the begining of a new group
     COALESCE((lag(COALESCE(b.street,'')) OVER(ORDER BY r.seq) ) 
        != COALESCE(b.street,''),true)  As is_grouping  
FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id,    
                          source::integer,
                          target::integer,
                          cost::double precision AS cost 
                          FROM my_table',                                                                                      
                              get_nearest_vertex_to_lon_lat(lat_st, long_st),       
                              get_nearest_vertex_to_lon_lat(-9.1511504, 38.7487786), 
                                    false, 
                                    false) 
a LEFT JOIN my_table b ON (a.id2 = b.gid) )
-- break distinct groups into ranges
 ps AS (SELECT p.seq AS start_seq, 
       COALESCE((lead(p.seq) OVER (ORDER BY p.seq) - 1),p.seq) As end_seq
     FROM p  
   WHERE is_grouping
 )
-- aggregate by grouping sets
SELECT ps.start_seq, ps.end_seq, p.street, SUM(p.cost) As cost,   
   ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Union(p.geom)) As gjson
  FROM p INNER JOIN ps ON (p.seq BETWEEN ps.start_seq AND ps.end_seq)
  GROUP BY ps.start_seq, ps.end_seq, p.street
  ORDER BY ps.start_seq;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no built-in function in pgRouting. But you can use PostgreSQL and PostGIS aggregate functions, such as `sum` for your `cost` column and [`ST_Collect`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) or [`ST_Union`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) for geometries.